# Eventbrite API - possible to have multiple expansions?

Tags: php, eventbrite

I'm using Eventbrite's API to get Event data, with the following code:

```
file_get_contents('https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/users/me/events?time_filter=current_future&status=live&expand=venue&token='.$eventbrite_private_token);
```

Is it possible to use multiple expansions in a single call? E.g. both expand=venue and expand=ticket_availability

I tried &expand=venue&expand=ticket_availability in the query string but that only returns one of the expansions, not both

If it's possible, what's the correct format?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is supported. There are currently two supported expansion versions, it is recommended that you use the new one:

This is what you should use:

```
/v3/users/me/events/?expand.event=organizer,venue
```

If you still need the old format for some reason, this is how it's done:

```
/v3/users/me/events/?expand=organizer,venue
```

For reference please see https://www.eventbrite.com/platform/api#/introduction/expansions